# Creating command in C

Tags: c, command

Greeings,

I have a rather peculiar question.

I'm currently coding in C and I wanted to implement a shortcut command for the user ( `CTRL + C` ) that can be used at any moment during an .exe being run and I have no idea on how to make it, without having to resort to `scanf()`.
I want the user to be able to just cancel whatever he was doing by just pressing that combination of buttons. Is there a way or do İ have to resort to a `while` with `scanf()`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use signals for that .For example you can create a function where there put what ever you want to do lets say :

```
void action(int handle){
    //do something here ,put here your code for this user 
}
```

and in your main function you can handle ctr+c like that :

```
signal(SIGINT,action);
```

Comment: `action()` should have one `int` parameter.

Comment: oo yes i forgot that when i was trying to explain thank you for that .